# Use of Zombie Dragon Breath Weapon as an Animate Dead Summon

Tags: pathfinder-2e, undead, dragons

I was wondering if it is possible to use the Zombie Dragon's Breath weapon from Pathfinder 2E's Animate Dead spell rules as written or even rules as intended.

Summoned creatures have the **minion** trait:
Minions are creatures that directly serve another creature. **A creature with this trait can use only 2 actions per turn, doesn't have reactions, and can't act when it's not your turn.**

Zombies such as the Zombie Dragon typically have the **slowed 1** status permanently, which states:
**You have fewer actions.** Slowed always includes a value. When you regain your actions at the start of your turn, reduce the number of actions you regain by your slowed value. Because slowed has its effect at the start of your turn, you don't immediately lose actions if you become slowed during your turn.

The Zombie Dragon's Breath Weapon requires two actions to use.

Would the combination of these traits make it impossible to command a zombie dragon to use their breath weapon? Is that what is intended for the game?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a recent [clarification](https://paizo.com/pathfinder/faq), Paizo confirmed that Minions can be Quickened or Slowed

> **Can a minion be quickened or slowed?**
> Yes. This can be a bit unclear because those conditions apply “at the start of your turn” and a minion can’t typically act until you use an action. Apply these conditions and any other effects that alter a minion’s number of actions when the minion gains its actions, using 2 actions and 0 reactions as the minion’s starting number.

So yes, summoned zombies only getting one action is working as intended. However, that doesn't mean it can't use its Breath Weapon. The [Gaining and Losing Actions](https://2e.aonprd.com/Conditions.aspx?ID=32) sidebar states

> The action gained from Haste lets you only Stride or Strike, so if you need to lose one action because you’re also Slowed, you might decide to lose the action from Haste, letting you keep your other actions that can be used more flexibly.

If the summoned zombie gains the Quickened condition from Haste or another effect, you can have it lose that action per the Slowed condition, and still retain two regular actions with which it can use its Breath Weapon.